# Which procedure should I do before using a water filter after being unused for two years?

Tags: water-purification, storage

I have a Katadyn hiker pro. I used it for the last time was two years ago and then I stored it without following the procedure for long term storage. This procedure consists in using it with water purified with tablets and should serve to clean the filter from bacteria which eventually can grow. In a month, I will need it for a trip to Africa, so what should I do with the katadyn? Use it as it is? Replacing the filter (that is rather expensive)?

Comment: Replace the filter would be prudent

Comment: I would contact Katadyn customer service - they will know their product better than anyone here. Though as @Paparazzi says, you would be better to err on the side of prudence.

Comment: I have already contacted Katadyn, but I haven't got any answer.

Comment: Thanks to all for the suggestions! I will try to clean the filter.